# Nested dictionary to pandas df concatenating rows

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize, glom

Given the following dict:

```
j = {
  "source": "https://example.com",
  "timestamp": "2021-04-12T19:34:24Z",
  "durationInTicks": 1082400000,
  "duration": "PT1M48.24S",
  "combinedRecognizedPhrases": [
    {
      "channel": 0,
      "lexical": "aaa",
      "itn": "aaa",
      "maskedITN": "aaa",
      "display": "aaa"
    }
  ],
  "recognizedPhrases": [
    {
      "recognitionStatus": "Success",
      "channel": 0,
      "speaker": 1,
      "offset": "PT2.18S",
      "duration": "PT3.88S",
      "offsetInTicks": 21800000,
      "durationInTicks": 38800000,
      "nBest": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.9306252,
          "lexical": "gracias por llamar",
          "itn": "gracias por llamar",
          "maskedITN": "gracias por llamar",
          "display": "¿Gracias por llamar",
          "words": [
            {
              "word": "gracias",
              "offset": "PT2.18S",
              "duration": "PT0.37S",
              "offsetInTicks": 21800000,
              "durationInTicks": 3700000,
              "confidence": 0.930625
            },
            {
              "word": "por",
              "offset": "PT2.55S",
              "duration": "PT0.18S",
              "offsetInTicks": 25500000,
              "durationInTicks": 1800000,
              "confidence": 0.930625
            },
            {
              "word": "llamar",
              "offset": "PT2.73S",
              "duration": "PT0.22S",
              "offsetInTicks": 27300000,
              "durationInTicks": 2200000,
              "confidence": 0.930625
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "recognitionStatus": "Success",
      "channel": 0,
      "speaker": 2,
      "offset": "PT6.85S",
      "duration": "PT5.63S",
      "offsetInTicks": 68500000,
      "durationInTicks": 56300000,
      "nBest": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.9306253,
          "lexical": "quiero hacer un pago",
          "itn": "quiero hacer un pago",
          "maskedITN": "quiero hacer un pago",
          "display": "quiero hacer un pago"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "recognitionStatus": "Success",
      "channel": 0,
      "speaker": 2,
      "offset": "PT13.29S",
      "duration": "PT3.81S",
      "offsetInTicks": 132900000,
      "durationInTicks": 38100000,
      "nBest": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.93062526,
          "lexical": "no sé bien la cantidad",
          "itn": "no sé bien la cantidad",
          "maskedITN": "no sé bien la cantidad",
          "display": "no sé bien la cantidad"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Goal**:  to get the information of interest in a single row of a df.

**What have I done so far?**:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(j, record_path=['recognizedPhrases', 'nBest'], meta=['source', 'durationInTicks', 'duration', ['recognizedPhrases', 'speaker']])
df['speech'] = df.groupby(['source', 'recognizedPhrases.speaker'])['display'].transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['recognizedPhrases.speaker'])
```

**Obtained df**:
[image]

**Why am I not satisfied with the output I have obtained?**: My output presents a df with two rows (one row for each `recognizedPhrases.speaker`) and I need all the information in one row, one column for what speaker 1 said (which is in the `speaker` column) and another column for what `speaker` 2 said.

**Additional information**: Performance is an important factor since I will be doing this process with thousands of files.

**Edit 1**:
The result I expect would look something like this:

```
expected_dict = {'source': {0: 'https://example.com'},
 'durationInTicks': {0: 1082400000},
 'duration': {0: 'PT1M48.24S'},
 'recognizedPhrases.speaker1': {0: '¿Gracias por llamar'},
 'recognizedPhrases.speaker2': {0: 'quiero hacer un pago no sé bien la cantidad'}}
expected_df = pd.DataFrame(expected_dict)
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output, as data ,not pics

Comment: @sammywemmy Thank you for taking a look at my question. It is difficult to publish the expected results as data, because I have not yet managed to get to that. But I edited the question to include an example of what the ideal result would look like. I wrote this result by hand, I did not get it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`pivot()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) into the expected output:

```py
index = ['source', 'durationInTicks', 'duration']
columns = ['recognizedPhrases.speaker']
values= ['speech']

df = df[index+columns+values].pivot(index=index, columns=columns, values=values[0])
df.columns = [f'{df.columns.name}{column}' for column in df.columns]
```

| source | durationInTicks | duration | recognizedPhrases.speaker1 | recognizedPhrases.speaker2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://example.com | 1082400000 | PT1M48.24S | ¿Gracias por llamar | quiero hacer un pago no sé bien la cantidad |